# linux commandline can connect but webserver (or php) can't connect

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php, selinux

We can connect to a specific url with linux (centos 6) commandline (`curl`, `wget`,...)

But we can't connect to it by webserver (apache) or php.

I did `setenforce 0` command, after that webserver and php can connect.

Which selinux rule cause this problem and how can connect by webserver(or php) when selinux is enabled ?

Comment: solved by: setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it. Ideally, clearly explain what file you had to add that line to.That way, the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1`